# Reference an index type while creating a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I have a scenario where I have a union of different types that all have a similar signature. I want to create a mapped type so I can look up all my types by an id:

```js
type Apple = {
    name: "apple", 
    value: 1, 
}; 

type Banana = {
    name: "banana", 
    value: "foobar"
}; 

type Cherry = {
    name: "cherry", 
    value: () => "hi"
}; 

type AllTypes = Apple | Banana | Cherry; 

type AllTypeKeys = AllTypes['name']; 


type TypeMap = {
    "apple": Apple; 
    "banana": Banana; 
    "cherry": Cherry; 
}
```

I can do it manually, as I have done in the TypeMap.

However, I would prefer to do something like this:

```js
type TypeMap = {
   [F['name'] in AllTypes]: F; 
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. Is there something similar that would?

Comment: Recursive type with cache and Exclude should help

Comment: @captain-yossarian my answer has the wrong information I deleted the post. You can continue with your answer. 

Comment: Please, provide an answer :) I have  SO vacation )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### As of TypeScript 4.1 you can use [Key Remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)

```
type TypeMap2 = {
  [K in AllTypes as K['name']]: K
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8BQVtQHYEMBbCALigCJ94lyAaKLHAN3wQFdSoBGejAXwDcDDKEhQAQvgIEoqTDjxFO5AEZT1dBgpbtlAMwD2BtQCdy-IRhHhoAYQAWEEyZCz0jbAWJlyAY0fOIJoeUDocZAAUAJSyAHwU9gCW5oLCotAwCAgAKjYAzm5wiNAAPhLqMmUOTi6W1mKZOTYA0hAgBaiNuZB5ANoA5F4Q-QC6dfXQ3RAAslRu8jiU1BDkZEVIlgqqFfir5dL4m4v+NUFk1YGWfFbpUFOzYABM84y9zVCJuLBZUwX4Bc0BkNRiMyM1+EA)

---

#### Prior to TypeScript 4.1 you can use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)

```
type TypeMap = {
  [V in AllTypes['name']]: Extract<AllTypes, { name: V }>
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8BQVtQHYEMBbCALigCJ94lyAaKLHAN3wQFdSoBGejAXwDcDDKEhQAQvgIEoqTDjxFO5AEZT1dBgpbtlAMwD2BtQCdy-IRhHhoAYQAWEEyZCz0jbAWJlyAY0fOIJoeUDocZAAUAJSyAHwU9gCW5oLCotAwCAgAKjYAzm5wiNAAPhLqMmUOTi6W1mKZOTYA0hAgBaiNuZB5ANoA5F4Q-QC6delQ3RAAslRu8lC9AGpQibiwWVN9g0qjI2QAogAewCb4vsAAPF359GiK3lArfLH8GEA)

---

More generic type can be defined as

```
type MapByKey<T, U extends keyof T > = {
  [K in T as K[U] & (string | number | symbol)]: K
}


// or prior to TS 4.1
type MapByKey<T, U extends keyof T > = {
  [V in T[U] & (string | number | symbol)]: Extract<T, Record<U, V>>
}

type TypeMap3 = MapByKey<AllTypes, 'name'>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=43&pln=31&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8BQVtQHYEMBbCALigCJ94lyAaKLHAN3wQFdSoBGejAXwDcDDKEhQAQvgIEoqTDjxFO5AEZT1dBgpbtlAMwD2BtQCdy-IRhHhoAYQAWEEyZCz0jbAWJlyAY0fOIJoeUDocZAAUAJSyAHwU9gCW5oLCotAwCAgAKjYAzm5wiNAAPhLqMmUOTi6W1mKZOTYA0hAgBaiNuZB5ANoA5F4Q-QC6dfXQ3RAAslRu8jiU1BDkZEVIlgqqFfir5dL4m4v+NUFk1YGWfFbpUFOzYABM84y9zVCJuLBZUwX4Bc0BkNRiMyM1+DcbFAHuIQK0QAAebL0ACqUAgAA9gBBcAATAoAazaBj0dyg8Tkr3enzJ-yggJRIygADIoBE8sATJ8AOZQMq4NiEFROPlQPIgIUGBBRUH0iETO42B4AZjcMLhbQRXXy9EGSn6sSAA)